# The tags fps and frame-rate should be synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tags [fps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fps) and [frame-rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frame-rate) should be synonyms, I think.

The two terms mean the same.

Comment: Its more that they both need to disappear entirely.

Comment: For now - I've set `fps` to point to `frame-rate` which seems to make the most sense to me... we can undo/reverse that if necessary...

Comment: @JonClements [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: Does frame-rate have to be in seconds really? i.e. "It has a frame-rate of 10 per minute", or whatever...

Comment: @JohnyTex no, it doesn't, which is probably one reason why Jon synonymized it the direction he did; [tag:frame-rate] covers any time measure, while [tag:fps] is only frame-rate per second.

Comment: I don't understand why fps exists/existed as a tag at all - it's an ambiguous acronym. Without the "frame-rate" context, I would have assumed it to mean first-person shooter.

Comment: @kjhf agreed but that's why tag descriptions exist :) You can really prevent tags from being or becoming ambiguous. the [tag:jsf] tag isn't about joint strike fighters for example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was done. I am posting this as answer just for making this accepted by OP (if possible).